# Getting directory info from S3 bucket: Error: Key is a directory

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I am using AWS SDk for .NET, I am trying to get the directory info from an S3 bucket.

The following code works and I can get the files in my root `folder`

```
// path: folder
S3DirectoryInfo di = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, "myS3BucketName", "folder");

if (di.Exists)
{
    IS3FileSystemInfo[] files = di.GetFileSystemInfos();
}
```

Now I try the same code, and query a `sub-folder` under `folder`, the code gets the directory info... but while reading the file contents, it throws exception

```
// path: folder/sub-folder
S3DirectoryInfo di = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, "myS3BucketName", "folder/sub-folder");

if (di.Exists)
{
    // directory exists, but reading files throws exception
    IS3FileSystemInfo[] files = di.GetFileSystemInfos();
}
```

This is the exception:

> Key is a directory

This is how I initialize the s3Client:

```
s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("Ak...access-key...", "+8b...secret-key...", RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was using slash in the path... when using high-level APIs, you need to use backslash in the path.

*Note: you need to use slash in the path when using AWS low-level API.*

This code works fine:

```
// path: folder\sub-folder\
string path = @"folder\sub-folder\";
S3DirectoryInfo di = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, "myS3BucketName", path);

if (di.Exists)
{
    // directory exists, but reading files throws exception
    IS3FileSystemInfo[] files = di.GetFileSystemInfos();
}
```